# What is the most accurate and efficient general-purpose eigenvalue algorithm?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Most likely, I will be dealing with a spare symmetric matrix, but I want to create a general purpose function in c++ that can efficiently and accurately calculate all the eigenvalues and their eigenvectors of any real matrices whether it be symmetric or non-symmetric, or tridiagonal .... etc

What are the possible algorithms?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm ? See also e.g. https://github.com/nom-de-guerre/Matrices

Comment: it seems QR algorithm is suitable for dense matrices only.   http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter4.pdf

Comment: What you ask is beyond any single person. I recommend that you either narrow your scope or seek employment with one of the groups which have been working on this problem for the past 25+ years.